# How do I convert this JSON string enclosed in double quotes to object

Tags: java, json, spring

My application receives an encrypted json from front end, I decrypt it on backend but it is formatted like this:

```
"{\"firstname\":\"JOHN\",\"lastname\":\"DOE\"}"
```

yes, there are leading and trailing double quotes on the decrypted json.

GSON and object mapper doesnt work since they detect the quotes on the first character.

Is there way to properly convert this without manually removing the enclosing quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your data has been double-encoded, so the solution is to double-decode. Specifically: thanks to the backslashes, this is actually a valid JSON *string* value that represents a stringified JSON object. So if you ask your JSON library to decode this into a `String`, you should get a string whose value is

```
{"firstname":"JOHN","lastname":"DOE"}
```

And then you can ask your JSON library to decode *that* string into the type you actually want.

Comment: I did String s = new JSONParser(str).string and got

    `{\"firstname\":\"JOHN\",\"lastname\":\"DOE\"}`


I'm off work but I'll try doing it again on the output string and update this again with the final solution I'll come up with.

Comment: @askwer: Which library is `JSONParser` from? You mentioned both GSON and ObjectMapper, and neither seems to contain a class with that name, at least not with JSON in all-uppercase.

Comment: aasmund-eldhuset, The JSONParser I mentioned above is from org.apache.tomcat.util.json (the @ tag won't work)

Comment: Final solution I ended up with:

Using JsonParser from GSON

`String newStr = JsonParser.parseString(oldStr).getAsString();`

I'm now getting the format that I need: 
`{"firstname":"JOHN","lastname":"DOE"}`

Comment: @askwer: Yep, that looks right - you ask the parser to interpret the original string as a JSON string value; then you can feed the result back into the JSON parser again and ask it to interpret it as a JSON object.